# How to specify number of characters to display in number formatting in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible in excel to specify the number of characters to be shown by cells? I'd like every cell to display the same number of characters, so the number of digits on the left and right of a decimal point would vary depending on the number of characters I specify. For example, I'd like each number

```
3
47.5
-999.25
600000
```

to be formatted to 7 characters in length:

```
3.00000
47.5000
-999.25
600000.
```

Comment: Yes you can do that by selecting the cells and go to cell formating. I'm not at my computer now so unfortunately I can't help you more.

Comment: This could be very misleading: what would you do with numbers that won't fit the format, such as 1000000000 or 0.000000001? An underflow could round to 0.00000, which wouldn't be too bad, but an overflow?

Comment: It's a good point. Ideally I'd use the maximum number of "real" characters (i.e. characters that aren't just padding) from the entire set of cells being formatted to determine the number of chars to use. In the example I give, `-999.25` has the most "real" characters (7), so that would be the number applied to all other cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I would never do this as it's incredibly hard to read. But here's one ugly solution:

[image]

Here's the same table showing formulas and column headers:

[image]

And the formulas for easier copying/pasting:

- C3: `=TEXT(B3,"0.000000")`
- D3: `=FIND(".",C3)`
- E3: `=LEFT(C3,D3-1)`
- F3: `=MID(C3,D3+1,99)`
- G3: `=E3&"."&LEFT(F3,6-LEN(E3))`

Comment: Misses the negative sign in the `-999.25` but very clever nonetheless. Thank you.

Comment: @dagrha My pleasure, and sorry! I was trying something else that was requiring `ABS()` on the second column, but that's entirely necessary actually. I'll fix my answer

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:

[image]

If you run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    Dim DQ As String

    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "0.000000"
        s = r.Text
        s = Left(s, 7)
        s = DQ & s & DQ
        r.NumberFormat = s & ";" & s & ";" & s
    Next r
End Sub
```

It will assign a separate custom NumberFormat to each cell:

[image]

The column should be "extra wide" to handle intermediate values.*There is a limit to the number of cells that can be formatted in this way because there is a limit to the number of custom numberformats.*

Comment: Dang, that's awesome.

Comment: @dagrha  **Please read the last sentence in my answer.**